# Are two solars panels more efficient than only one of twice the power output?

Tags: electrical-engineering, battery, solar-energy, photovoltaics, solar

Is there any advantage to use two 50 W solar panels in parallels instead of one 100 W panel?

As we know, the effect of partial shadow on a solar panel can make the whole panel ineffective. We want to mitigate this effect by doubling the panels so there's always 50% effectiveness but we're unable to find data on that subject.

Comment: Partial shading only affects cells in series. So I guess it would depend on how the cells are arranged and connected in the 100W panel. The more cells are in parallel in the same panel, the less of a problem partial shading would be. But if the entire 100W panel consisted of only a single string of series cells then it would be greatly impacted.

Comment: Yes, what you are suggesting makes sense. Another thing you can do is point them NE and NW, this reduces your total energy take but provides power for longer during the day.

Comment: It may be hard to find specific case data because solar setups are so easily modeled, and modeled for specific sites.  You do need to be aware that the effect of splitting panels with bypass capabilities is not free.  Bypassing shaded panels comes at a cost of power loss in diodes- losses that are hurtful during normal  unshaded operation.  If you fill out sun charts with the right info, you can model it into power and ultimately overall efficiency over a year or even expected life of panel.